# Merge/Synonym [jquery-blockui] and [blockui]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

Please merge/synonym the tags [jquery-blockui](/questions/tagged/jquery-blockui) and [blockui](/questions/tagged/blockui). They are duplicates. I think the trend is for the jQuery prefix, so I suggest [jquery-blockui](/questions/tagged/jquery-blockui) as the main tag, and [blockui](/questions/tagged/blockui) as the synonym.